# Read specific element out of IEnumerable<XElement>

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have this block of XML:

```
<Books>
  <BookData id="BookID_100">
    <Name>The Catcher and the Rye</Name>
    <Description>This is a neat book that you might have had to read in school</Description>
    <Date>1/1/1900</Date>
    <IsHardcover>1</IsHardcover>
  </BookData>
  <BookData id="BookID_101">
    <Name>Harry Potter</Name>
    <Description>J.K. Rowlings Fantasy Epic</Description>
    <Date>1/1/2000</Date>
    <IsHardcover>0</IsHardcover>
  </BookData>
</Books>
```

I'm reading a single 'book' into memory as an IEnumerable:

```
IEnumerable<XElement> book =
  from el in root.Elements("BookData")
  where (string)el.Attribute("id") == "BookID_100"
  select el;
```

Now, from here, how do retrieve a value based on the tag?  Say, I want the 'Name' data.  How do I get a string with the content, "The Catcher and The Rye"?  This seems like it should be simple, but I everything I see is extremely esoteric and unwieldly when all I want to do is

```
// Pseudo Code
string bookName = book.GetElementByID("Name").ToString();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to call `Element` method and pass the element name of  which you want to get from the `XElement`:

```
IEnumerable<XElement> book =
  from el in root.Elements("BookData")
  where el.Attribute("id").Value == "BookID_100"
  select el.Element("Name");
```

This will return you only the element `Name` of your Node. You can further call `.Value` property to get the text between the opening and closing tag of `Name` tag.

If you need only single book  as it looks like you will get one book back against an id you would need to write:

```
var book =
      (from el in root.Elements("BookData")
       where el.Attribute("id").Value == "BookID_100"
       select el).FirstOrDefault();

 if(book !=null)
 {
    string Name  = book.Element("Name").Value;
 }
```

Comment: use `FirstOrDefault()` for single item

Answer (score 3):

Why are you getting a collection of book elements when you clearly only want the book with the specified ID?  If you only want the one book you can just use `FirstOrDefault()`

Try this instead:

```
//This will return the first book matching: "BookID_100" or NULL
var book = root.Elements("BookData")
                  .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Attribute("id") == "BookID_100");

//'name' will be null if book or name is null, or the name of the book element
string name = book?.Element("Name")?.Value;
```

If you are not using C#6 or above then the `?.` operator will not be available to you, in that case just check for null like usual:

```
string name = string.Empty;
if(book != null && book.Element("Name") != null)
{ 
    name = book.Element("Name").Value;
}
```